# bad-setting error, bad unit file setting (ubuntu server 22.04.3)

Tags: server, systemd

I have made a terraria server and I want it to launch on startup in a new screen session. It also runs a minecraft server, for which I use mcrcon to send commands, but I dont think terraria supports rcon so i want it to start in a screen session so I can send commands. I duct taped together various service files off of the internet, and this is what I have. Some of this is likely unnecessary, but oh well. My service file looks like this:

```
[root@terraria system]
[Unit]
Description=Start Tmod
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=penrosian
ExecStart=/root/start_tmod_server.bash
ExecStart=/usr/bin/screen -dmS autoscreen
ExecStop=/usr/bin/screen -S autoscreen -X quit
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and the referenced bash file (if useful) is

```
#!/bin/bash

#Standard tmod
cd /home/penrosian/terraria
exec ./start-tModLoaderServer.sh
```

but on reboot I find no screen session waiting for me, and `systemctl status terraria` yields me

```
○ terraria.service - Start Tmod
     Loaded: bad-setting (Reason: Unit terraria.service has a bad unit file setting.)
     Active: inactive (dead)
```

anyone know what is wrong here?